# How to get file read permission in Edge browser's native host

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to read the settings file from Edge browser's native host which is implemented in UWP. This settings file has some list of URLs to process it in extension. But I am not able to read the file in the native host. I am getting the following exception while reading the file.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Settings.dat' is denied.'

```
string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Sameer\\Desktop\\Settings.dat"; 
bool bfileExist = File.Exists(fileName); 
if (bfileExist) { byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); }
```

does anyone have any idea to read the file in Edge browser's native host? Please let me know.

Comment: So, you're developing an UWP app and want to read file from the path 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Settings.dat'?

Comment: Yes, I am developing the UWP app and want to read file from particular location.

Comment: Have you add [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) capability for your uwp app?

Comment: Yes, I have tried broadFileSystemAccess capability but it is giving the same error.

Comment: How do you get file in your  uwp app, could you share your code ?

Comment: And have you enable this capability in OS setting page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP has provided `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to access broader file with APIs in the `Windows.Storage namespace`. You need add the restricted `broadFileSystemAccess` capability before access. And please avoid use `System.IO` api.  For more please refer the following code.

```
var file= await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName);
if (file!= null)
{
    byte[] result;
    using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by using following code

```
string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Sameer\\Desktop\\Settings.dat";
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName);

if(file != null)
{
  var bufferData = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);               
  Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(bufferData);
  byte[] fileData = new byte[bufferData.Length];
  dataReader.ReadBytes(fileData);
}
```