# Display Data from Drive D: in the Gridview

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp

I have a gridview that displays data from drive D:

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Book> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
        Book book = new Book();
    book.Name = file.DisplayName.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
        try
        {
            string thumbPath = @"D:\Kipin\thumb\komik";
            StorageFolder komikthumb = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(thumbPath);
            thumbFile = await komikthumb.GetFileAsync(file.Name.ToString() + ".png");
            string path1 = komikthumb.Path;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path1, file.Name.ToString() + ".png");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                book.Image = thumbFile.Path;
            }
    catch
    {}
    }
 datasource.Add(book);
 this.komikGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
```

Book.cs:

```
public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

The code above does not succeed in displaying data from D in the gridview and get error message: `Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.`

I have also added a declaration to the package as shown below:
[declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qefJ2.png)

How to handle it?

Comment: So what actually does happen? "Nothing" is not an acceptable or accurate answer. You need to step through the code in the debugger and see what it actually does, as well as how and where that behaviour differs from your expectations. Not using an empty `catch` block that effectively ignores any and all exceptions would be the first step.

Comment: get error message `Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.`

Comment: BTW, the code you posted wouldn't compile so can't possibly be the code you're running. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You should be copying and pasting the relevant code directly from the code editor, so there's no excuse for it not to be valid and accurate.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit the question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem that you should have in the first place. You still haven't told us where the exception is thrown and what the actual file path is when it occurs. Going back and forth like this is a waste of our time and yours. Providing all the relevant information in the first place increases the likelihood of getting the help you want and sooner. Maybe we could have resolved the issue by now but I'm quickly losing interest.

Comment: I have added the error message to my post above before replying to you

Comment: Is it a UWP project? UWP runs in a sandbox and cannot directly access the file in drive D. You need to declare [file permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) for your app and turn on file permissions in settings.

Comment: I have declared file permissions, but still can't display data from drive D: on gridview

Comment: And have you enabled this feature in the system app setting page. It is noteworthy that `broadFileSystemAccess` only avaiable for windows storage api, for more details please refer this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325904/7254781)